# Receive push notifications on multiple devices in Google Chat

Tags: gmail, google-chat

I recently started using Google Chat and ran into an issue while on my Mac. Notifications were appearing only when the tab was open. After reading the [support article](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/7655718?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&oco=0), I presume this is because I got notified on my phone, and Google Chat will only notify one device at a time. However, I'd like to receive notifications on **both devices**, regardless of whether the tab is open.